# sendmail on Mac OS X cannot send mail to a particular domain

Tags: macos, git, email, localhost, postfix-mta

I'm trying to set up sendmail on a Mac OS X machine. It's really weird that it works with my gmail address, but not any addresses under @umich.edu. I think it has something to do with my host setup, since the server is running at hostname xxxx.umich.edu. And I also tried other domains like xxxx@ucsd.edu, it didn't work either.

I think sendmail actually tries to send the email to local.server, which I don't understand.

And here the log from /var/mail/git (I'm not entirely sure why it's actually here, but the successfully sent emails to my gmail account also go to here):

```
--C3822326DF4F.1385583589/server.local--

From MAILER-DAEMON  Wed Nov 27 15:20:51 2013
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: git@server.local
Delivered-To: git@server.local
Received: by server.local (Postfix)
  id 76104326DFE9; Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:51 -0500 (EST)
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:51 -0500 (EST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@server.local (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: git@server.local
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
  boundary="3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local"
Message-Id: <20131127202051.76104326DFE9@server.local>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This is the mail system at host server.local.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<yunqi@umich.edu>: host mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87] said: 550 Unknown host:
    server.local (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; server.local
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 3A17D326DFE1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; git@server.local
Arrival-Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; yunqi@umich.edu
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx2.umich.edu
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Unknown host: server.local

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <git@server.local>
Received: by server.local (Postfix, from userid 505)
  id 3A17D326DFE1; Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)
To: yunqi@umich.edu
Subject: Put a subject here
From: to_whoever@example.org
Message-Id: <20131127202050.3A17D326DFE1@server.local>
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)

Of cause, here's the place to put the body

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local--

From MAILER-DAEMON  Wed Nov 27 15:20:51 2013
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: git@server.local
Delivered-To: git@server.local
Received: by server.local (Postfix)
  id 76929326DFEA; Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:51 -0500 (EST)
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:51 -0500 (EST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@server.local (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Mail Delivery Status Report
To: git@server.local
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
  boundary="3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local"
Message-Id: <20131127202051.76929326DFEA@server.local>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This is the mail system at host server.local.

Enclosed is the mail delivery report that you requested.

                   The mail system

<yunqi@umich.edu>: delivery via mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87]:25: host
    mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87] said: 550 Unknown host: server.local (in
    reply to MAIL FROM command)

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; server.local
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 3A17D326DFE1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; git@server.local
Arrival-Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; yunqi@umich.edu
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx2.umich.edu
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Unknown host: server.local

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local
Content-Description: Message Headers
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <git@server.local>
Received: by server.local (Postfix, from userid 505)
  id 3A17D326DFE1; Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)
To: yunqi@umich.edu
Subject: Put a subject here
From: to_whoever@example.org
Message-Id: <20131127202050.3A17D326DFE1@server.local>
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 15:20:49 -0500 (EST)

--3A17D326DFE1.1385583651/server.local--
```

And hereis the log from /var/log/mail.log:

```
Nov 27 15:20:13 server.local postfix/master[64261]: master exit time has arrived
Nov 27 15:20:50 server.local postfix/master[64355]: daemon started -- version 2.9.4, configuration /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix
Nov 27 15:20:50 server.local postfix/pickup[64356]: 3A17D326DFE1: uid=505 from=<git>
Nov 27 15:20:50 server.local postfix/cleanup[64358]: 3A17D326DFE1: message-id=<20131127202050.3A17D326DFE1@server.local>
Nov 27 15:20:50 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 3A17D326DFE1: from=<git@server.local>, size=338, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/smtp[64360]: 3A17D326DFE1: to=<yunqi@umich.edu>, relay=mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.86/0.01/1.2/0.03, dsn=5. 0.0, status=bounced (host mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87] said: 550 Unknown host: server.local (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/cleanup[64358]: 76104326DFE9: message-id=<20131127202051.76104326DFE9@server.local>
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 76104326DFE9: from=<>, size=2142, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/bounce[64366]: 3A17D326DFE1: sender non-delivery notification: 76104326DFE9
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/cleanup[64358]: 76929326DFEA: message-id=<20131127202051.76929326DFEA@server.local>
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 76929326DFEA: from=<>, size=1898, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/bounce[64367]: 3A17D326DFE1: sender delivery status notification: 76929326DFEA
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 3A17D326DFE1: removed
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/local[64368]: 76104326DFE9: to=<git@server.local>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to   mailbox)
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 76104326DFE9: removed
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/local[64368]: 76929326DFEA: to=<git@server.local>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to   mailbox)
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/qmgr[64357]: 76929326DFEA: removed
Nov 27 15:21:50 server.local postfix/master[64355]: master exit time has arrived
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is everything explained in the last part of that line:

```
Nov 27 15:20:51 server.local postfix/smtp[64360]: 3A17D326DFE1: to=<yunqi@umich.edu>, relay=mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.86/0.01/1.2/0.03, dsn=5. 0.0, status=bounced (host mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87] said: 550 Unknown host: server.local (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

As you can see the message you sent to the relay **mx2.umich.edu[141.211.124.87]** is bounced with the following error: **550 Unknown host: server.local (in reply to MAIL FROM command))** which explains itself pretty well.

From [this link](http://info.webtoolhub.com/kb-a15-smtp-status-codes-smtp-error-codes-smtp-reply-codes.aspx) you can see what the SMTP code **550** exactly means, and it is similar to the explanation returned by the server in your case:
**SMTP Error 550 will be returned by many servers If the recipient email address simply does not exist on the remote side.**

So it seems that the particular server you are trying to reach is configured to check if the remote domain is valid but unfortunately **server.local** is not a valid domain name.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So how can I actually configure the remote domain, because I don't think server.local is a valid domain either.